# Creating result array based on 2 arrays using JavaScript ES6 Reduce method

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reduce

Hi actually i have two arrays ( services and offer) and i'm trying connect offer array with service array based on service id using reduce method and i tried different method but nothing working i'm not able to solve this check my  [js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kg6981ce/) (not able to connect with offer array). please help me to resolve this. thanks in advance

```
const services = [
                   {
                    cid:1,
                    catname:'Facial',
                    services:[
                      {
                       sid:30,
                       sname:'Fruit facial'
                      },
                      {
                       sid:33,
                       sname:'Herbal facial'
                      }
                    ]
                   },
                   {
                    cid:2,
                    catname:'Massage',
                    services:[
                      {
                       sid:40,
                       sname:'Head Massage'
                      },
                      {
                       sid:45,
                       sname:'Back Massage'
                      },
                      {
                       sid:46,
                       sname:'Face Massage'
                      }
                    ]
                   }
            ]
```

Offer Array - here based on service id (sid) i want to connect with services array and create new array

```
const offer = [
               {
                 offid:1,
                 sid:'33,40'
                 offvalue : 10%
               },
               {
                 offid:2,
                 sid:'45,46',
                 offvalue : 100
               }
             ]
```

Expecting Result:

```
const Result = [
                   {
                    cid:1,
                    catname:'Facial',
                    services:[
                      {
                       sid:30,
                       sname:'Fruit facial'
                      },
                      {
                       sid:33,
                       sname:'Herbal facial',
                       offid:1,
                       offvalue : 10%
                      }
                    ]
                   },
                   {
                    cid:2,
                    catname:'Massage',
                    services:[
                      {
                       sid:40,
                       sname:'Head Massage',
                       offid:1,
                       offvalue : 10%
                      },
                      {
                       sid:45,
                       sname:'Back Massage',
                       offid:2,
                       offvalue : 100
                      },
                      {
                       sid:46,
                       sname:'Face Massage',
                       offid:2,
                       offvalue : 100
                      }
                    ]
                   }
           ]
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Please show your code as an [mcve].

Comment: @Andy hi please check my link https://jsfiddle.net/kg6981ce/  i tried that since i'm new to JavaScript so not able to finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use ES6 features, then this should work:

```js
const services = [{
  cid:1,
  catname:'Facial',
  services: [{
    sid:30,
    sname:'Fruit facial'
  }, {
    sid:33,
    sname:'Herbal facial'
  }],
}, {
  cid:2,
  catname:'Massage',
  services: [{
    sid:40,
    sname:'Head Massage'
  }, {
    sid:45,
    sname:'Back Massage'
  }, {
    sid:46,
    sname:'Face Massage'
  }],
}];

const offer = [{
  offid:1,
  sid:'33,40',
  offvalue : "10%"
}, {
  offid:2,
  sid:'45,46',
  offvalue : "100"
}];

const result = services.map(val => {
  return {
    ...val,
    services: val.services.map(serv => {
      // Here is where we find any matching offers, then add their data to the service.
      const off = offer.find(x => x.sid.split(",").includes(String(serv.sid)));
      if (off) {
        serv.offid = off.offid;
        serv.offvalue = off.offvalue;
      }
      return serv;
    }),
  }
});

console.log(result);
```